Appropriate directory structure for a project with React frontend and Express backend
I am currently in the process of developing a web application. I am using React with Vite for the frontend and Express for the backend.
The app that is going to be developed will be connecting to an Oracle database and the general idea is a management system that includes multiple user roles each with their own interactive view. It will be in production I have not decided where to deploy it yet.
I would appreciate feedback and tips regarding my folder structure and any other consideration I should have diving into this. My current folder structure looks like this:
|   .gitignore
|   package-lock.json
|   package.json
|   README.md
|
+---client
|   |   eslint.config.js
|   |   index.html
|   |   package-lock.json
|   |   package.json
|   |   vite.config.js
|   |
|   +---public
|   |       vite.svg
|   |
|   \---src
|       |   App.css
|       |   App.jsx
|       |   index.css
|       |   main.jsx
|       |
|       \---assets
|               react.svg
|
\---server
    |   eslint.config.mjs
    |   package-lock.json
    |   package.json
    |   server.js
    |
    \---routes
            api.js

